# SVN update or integrate

Tags: svn

I have a local copy that contains new and updated files, but hasn't been checked in for more than a year to our SVN repository.  The local copy is actually just a sub-directory of the repository.

I'm trying to update/commit the new local code to the correct directory in the repo.

What is the difference between updating or integrating the local code to the repo?
How would I make sure to update the correct sub-directory in the repo?

I've performed a diff to see which files are new/updated, but it is checking into the right directory that I'm unsure of.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Are the files that need to be checked in in a valid working copy? If so, you can just update and commit and they will go to the folder were thex belong. (Unless of course that folder no longer exists in HEAD.)

Comment: I will run svn status to validate.  If not, then what would be a recommendation to follow?

Comment: Depends. One solution would be to check out a new working copy of the folder, where the files should go, copy them there and then commit. I wouldn't be to worried about hitting the wrong folder, though. It's a version control system after all, so if you do something wrong, just undo or fix it.